# "Application Error. connection to server was unsuccessful" on release apk in Cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am working on an Angular + Cordova application. Everything seems to work fine in the debug build. No issues with the application. However, whenever I am trying to build a release APK, the build gets successful. But the application doesn't open and crashes with the following screen.

[image]

### My development environment

---

#### Angular

- @angular-devkit/build-angular: ~13.2.2
- @angular/core: ~13.2.0
- @angular/cli: ~13.2.2

#### Cordova

- Cordiva CLI - 11
- Cordova-android - 8.1.0

#### Node & NPM

- NodeJS : v14.17.3
- npm: 6.14.16
- OS: macOS Monterey 12.2.1

#### Cordova plugins

- "com.cordova.plugins.cookiemaster": "^1.0.1"
- "cordova-android": "^8.1.0"
- "cordova-ios": "^6.1.0"
- "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.13"
- "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0"
- "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3"
- "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2"
- "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.1.0"
- "cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions": "^1.2.0"
- "cordova-plugin-proguard": "^2.2.0"
- "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4"
- "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2"
- "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5"
- "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0"

N.B. - I upgraded the `cordova-android` to the latest but the issue still remains.

I have also tried the existing fixes in the StackOverflow nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with `cordova-plugin-proguard`. Once I removed it, everything worked fine. It looks like `cordova-plugin-proguard` is not yet supported for Angular 13.